# What is the difference between the height specifications "PDF" and "Probability" for Histogram built-in function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

maybe this question is something conceptual but I need to clarify it.

Given a data I can use Histogram to plot the distribution of the frequencies of the data. If I need  the relative frequencies I can use the height specification "Probability" for the Histogram built-in function. In principle we don't know the probability distribution function of the population, but our histogram approximates that distribution. I really need to understand what represent the height specification "PDF" for the histogram and how are calculated those heights.

For example, here are the two different height specifications for the some data

```
datos={19, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 2, \
2, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"PDF" gives you the average probability within a bin, that is, multiply the value by bin width to get a bin's total probability.

"Probability" does this for you automatically.